# Python - Find and replace regex substring in a string variable

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a variable with a multiline string and I'm trying to replace the line `test v1.0` with `upside` but the problem is I'm trying to replace it only if the entire line matches the pattern so it shouldn't replace the first `test v1.0.1`

```
pkgLogExtract = dedent("""
                      test v1.0.1
                      nothing

                      test v1.0
                      out
                      in
                      flip
                      """)

print (re.sub(r'\^test v1.0\$', "upside", pkgLogExtract, 1))
```

I tried using `re.sub` and putting `'\^test v1.0\$'` as the pattern to replace but it doesn't replace anything. I've also tried it with the raw flag, so `r'\^test v1.0\$'` but that doesn't replace anything either. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: `\^` matches a literal `^`. Same goes about `$`. You need to pass `flags=re.M` to the `re.sub` and remove the backslashes from `^` and `$`. And escape the `.`. See http://ideone.com/ijPIra

Comment: Is `your_string.replace("test v1.0\n", "upside")` too brittle?

Comment: @jDo I couldn't be 100% sure that `replace` would work in every situation so I opted for regex (the above script is just pseudo code)

Comment: @TheGirrafish Makes sense. The regex is more "solid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\^` matches a literal `^`. Same goes about `$`. You need to pass `flags=re.M` to the `re.sub` and remove the backslashes from `^` and `$` so that they could match the start and end of line respectively. And escape the `.`.

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ijPIra):

```
import re
pkgLogExtract = """
test v1.0.1
nothing
test v1.0
out
in
flip
"""

print (re.sub(r'^test v1\.0$', "ngn", pkgLogExtract, 1, flags=re.M))
```

Note: I think you know that `1` stands for a single replacement (only the first match will get replaced).

Note 2: you may omit `flags=` and use `re.M`, but a lot of people forget to use the above mentioned *`count`* argument, so it is best to keep the argument name here.

Comment: Thanks it works great! I had tried it without the backslashes also but it wouldn't work either. I think the problem was that I was missing the re.M flag the entire time.

Comment: Possible. Also, the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot, and not a text like `test v1-0`